# Codesign error, flutter clean required every time

Tags: ios, flutter, codesign

Ok so I've have this issue which is

resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
Could not build the application for the simulator.

When building my `flutter` app.  After much investigation, and following what is written here [Codesign error with Flutter on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612211/codesign-error-with-flutter-on-ios)

Running `flutter clean` removes the error, however, when closing the simulator and re-running debug again the error is displayed... is there a more permanent fix for this?

I've also followed the commands outlined in this thread too [Code Sign Error in macOS High Sierra Xcode - resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652867/code-sign-error-in-macos-high-sierra-xcode-resource-fork-finder-information)

Answer (score 0):

In this case use xattr -cr. command in the Project Directory Terminal.