# Errors launching application on iOS

Tags: flutter

I am workimg on a Flutter project, but now, after developing over 20 project versions, the project is not launching on iOS device,it throws the following errors:

```
[   +2 ms] Failed to build iOS app
[   +1 ms] Error output from Xcode build:
           ↳
[        ]     ** BUILD FAILED **


[        ] Xcode's output:
           ↳
[        ]     /Users/modestovascofornas/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/images_picker-0.0.9/ios/Classes/SwiftImagesPickerPlugin.swift:6:8: error: no such module 'ZLPhotoBrowser'
               import ZLPhotoBrowser
                      ^
               note: Using new build system
               note: Building targets in parallel
               note: Planning build
               note: Analyzing workspace
               note: Constructing build description
               note: Build preparation complete
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'geolocator' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'permission_handler' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'location' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'libPhoneNumber-iOS' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'libphonenumber' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'firebase_storage' from project 'Pods')
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO 2021 ssd/X1-qPLAN-FLUTTER/flutter_qplan/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

[   +5 ms] Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
[   +4 ms] Error launching application on iPhone de Modes.
[   +4 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:474:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)


[{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"768eb2eb-2412-49dc-adaa-bd62d26b2bf0"}}]
[   +7 ms] "flutter run" took 57,641ms.
[{"id":0,"error":"app '768eb2eb-2412-49dc-adaa-bd62d26b2bf0' not found","trace":"#0      AppDomain.stop (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:721:7)\n#1      Domain.handleCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:220:34)\n#2      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:223:31)\n#3      Domain.handleCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:218:5)\n#4      Daemon._handleRequest (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:144:28)\n#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)\n#6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)\n#7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)\n#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)\n#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)\n#10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)\n#11     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:224:10)\n#12     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)\n#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)\n#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)\n#15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)\n#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)\n#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)\n#18     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:127:11)\n#19     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:199:12)\n#20     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)\n#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)\n#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)\n#23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)\n#24     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)\n#25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)\n#26     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:69:11)\n#27     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)\n#28     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)\n#29     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:155:13)\n#30     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:130:5)\n#31     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:163:5)\n#32     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:121:24)\n#33     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)\n#34     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)\n#35     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)\n#36     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)\n#37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)\n#38     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:69:11)\n#39     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:15:11)\n#40     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)\n#41     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:243:7)\n#42     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:317:20)\n#43     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5)\n#44     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)\n#45     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:121:24)\n#46     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)\n#47     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)\n#48     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)\n#49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)\n#50     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)\n#51     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:808:19)\n#52     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:682:7)\n#53     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:624:5)\n#54     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2044:41)\n#55     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)\n#56     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)\n#57     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)\n#58     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:357:11)\n#59     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:285:7)\n#60     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:808:19)\n#61     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:682:7)\n#62     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:624:5)\n#63     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1580:33)\n#64     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1076:14)\n#65     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)\n#66     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)\n#67     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)\n#68     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)\n"}]
[ +113 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 112ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[   +5 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

I am completely lost. I have tried for hours to implement other SO users solutions, but the issues are there.

EDIT:
Once executed pod update, this is the output:

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "images_picker":
  In Podfile:
    images_picker (from `.symlinks/plugins/images_picker/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `images_picker (from `.symlinks/plugins/images_picker/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

SECOND EDIT:

Now after implementing the changes proposed by @BLKKKBVSIK, there are lots of deprecated warnings and then the following output:

```
                                                                           ^
               1 warning generated.
               /Users/modestovascofornas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hjtmuaorpiiuycbpnpmnrphgfiez/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-8011B22625F6849D003622A3.sh: line 3: /Users/modestovascofornas/Documents/DESARROLLO: No such file or directory
               Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
               note: Using new build system
               note: Building targets in parallel
               note: Planning build
               note: Analyzing workspace
               note: Constructing build description
               note: Build preparation complete

[  +18 ms] Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
[   +8 ms] Error launching application on iPhone de Modes.
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:474:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Comment: Have you tried flutter clean or pod update in ios/?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612211/codesign-error-with-flutter-on-ios/50706615

Comment: @ZafarIqbal, I have edite my question to include the output to pod update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a higher deployment target for your Pods.

You may want to open your `Runner.xcworkspace` file located in the `ios` folder of your Flutter project.

Once opened, you may want to check out the minimum version for the `Pods` project.

[image: Pod Project Versionning]

You can also check the minimum version for the exact dependency (`images_picker` in your case)

[image: Dependency Versionning]

Finally, you can also add a minimum version at the top of your `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

// rest of Podfile content
```

You can also add at the end of your `Podfile` a script that will ensure that your dependencies are in a certain version after a `pod install`.
For that, you can add those lines at the end of the `Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: no success, after implementing all your proposals, now the output is showinng a lot of other errors

Comment: What are the errors ? Maybe we can go from there.

Comment: Fine, let me launch the iOS app and then I copy here the errors

Comment: I have just included the Log for the Run debugger after inserting your proposals in the code